# Unreal engine замедлился

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Замедлилась работа unreal engine, не знаю как исправить

Comment: ускорить работу unreal engine, знаю как исправить

Answer (score 3):

**Системные требования**

- Windows 7 64-bit или Mac OS X 10.9.2 или поздние версии.
- Процессор Intel or AMD, 2.5 GHz или выше.
- NVIDIA GeForce 470 GTX или AMD Radeon 6870 HD или выше.
- 8 GB RAM.

Если ваше устройство соответствует требование то стоит учесть следующее, **чем больше ваш проект тем больше оперативной памяти нужно**, допустим если ваш проект весит около 100 гб. то для него необходимо порядка 16 гб. или больше оперативной памяти.

Так же рекомендую убедится что ваша видеокарта поддерживает работу с основными шейдерами UE4 (это можно понять если у вас часто вылетает движок при работе с материалами или системой частиц, такие вылеты означают что видеокарта не может корректно работать с шейдерами движка). Если ваша видеокарта не поддерживает шейдеры движка то вы можете попробовать запустить движет на более ранний версии Direct X, например что бы запустить движет на Direct X 10 нужно добавить -dx10 в параметры запуска.